# android studio migrated code binary xml issue coming

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2, xml-layout, setcontentview

I have done successfully for eclipse code to android studio migration. for past two weeks. that code is working fine.but, suddenly, the home page( landing page, contains 10 menu options available with background image setted ) entered getting app crash issue.

note:  when i click the error. its going to the MainActivity.java setContentView xml layout only.

Error in studio :

```
05-10 18:46:46.354 11018-11018/com.vss.psp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.vss.psp, PID: 11018
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vss.psp/com.vss.controller.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #79: Error inflating class <unknown>
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:175)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:433)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:376)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2155)
at com.vss.controller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:203)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:175) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:433) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:376) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2155) 
at com.vss.controller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:203) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:572)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3745)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:149)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:141)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
at android.transition.Scene.enter(Scene.java:175) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.transitionTo(PhoneWindow.java:433) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:376) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2155) 
at com.vss.controller.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:203) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: put your xml file here

Comment: Paste the full log, usually there are a couple `caused by: ...` lines and you can find the error in your code.

Comment: Please put your xml file here.

Comment: complete error msg added above.pls check it